# Cannot seem to download command line tools

Tags: command-line, xcode

I'm trying to download and install Command Line Tools for my Mac through Xcode, but it is not in the downloads section like youtube videos tell me to go. So, I manually download it and install it, and it still does not show up. I need this so I can download MacPorts. Any suggestions on how to get it? Or how to see if I already have it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Run `xcode-select --install`**

This will prompt you to download and install the CLTs using softwareupdate.

[image]

Comment: When I do that, I get a dialog box that comes up and says "Cant install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server

Comment: @user38508 Do you have a custom software update server set? Is the machine under MDM? Is your account a network account through OS X Server? Try resetting your softwareupdate server: `sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL`

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what any of that means. lol. I'm a Mac Noob. I know the ins and out of windows because that is what I grew up on and have developed on. But I have recently switched over to Mac, and have no idea what anything is. lol

Comment: @user38508 Then your answer is probably no :) Try the reset command to reset the server address to make sure it really is calling Apple.

Comment: Ugh. One problem after another. Hopefully we can get this worked out. When I run the reset command, it says this: "Domain (/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate) not found.
Defaults have not been changed."